# zend framework: Creating the Default Module

Tags: zend-framework, default, modular

I did everything as it is written in the book of Vaswani V. - the Zend Framework. A Beginner's Guide (page 33), but the page "http://square.localhost/default/index/index" returns the response "not found". What is wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem in that book. thank u for asking the question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with that part of the book.  Fortunately, the book's companion site (zf-beginners-guide.com) has an errata/troubleshooting section that solves the problem nicely. Quoting from the site:

> If you see a "File not found" error after implementing the modular
>   directory layout and accessing the URL
>   http://square.localhost/default/index/index, check that the new
>   virtual host supports .htaccess overrides. You can enable this by
>   adding the following lines to your virtual host configuration,
>   remembering to change the directory path to your virtual host's
>   document root.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/square/public">
   AllowOverride All
   Options All
</Directory>
```

Incidentally, if you're using Ubuntu, it may not have mod_rewrite enabled by default. (I just ran into the exact same problem myself BTW). If you're still having trouble, try this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

(Big thanks to Mahok for the help on that, BTW!)

Comment: No problem. Incidentally, that book has a fair number of errors in it. If you're having problems with a particular part, try checking the errata section; it helped me a lot!